# Create subtabs using mootools.js

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2, mootools-more, mootools-fx, mootools-sortable

I would like to know is there a way to create tabs inside tabs using moo tools version 1.4. I tried but it looks like sub tabs not working

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by _"create tabs inside tabs"_? Is that a plugin? a menu? different pages in one that change with "tabs"?

Comment: sure. it's like this  [link]http://screencast.com/t/7cAod5qIXXAg[/link]
flags tab working . whole backend made by mootools JS, when menu (html, plain, preview) not in languages tabs div it's clicable and working but I put it as a sub tab it isn't